# SQLITE_CANTOPEN error when opening DB in READONLY mode

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I want to open database as READONLY:

```
exit = sqlite3_open_v2( "database.db?immutable=1" , &db_ , SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY | SQLITE_OPEN_URI , nullptr );
```

but I am getting error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN, any idea why?

If I open it like this, open is successfull:

```
exit = sqlite3_open( "database.db" , &db_ );
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. You should probably tag the appropriate language for what you are doing.

Comment: I'm confused why you are trying to combine using the `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY` flag with the `SQLITE_OPEN_URI` mode. I suggest trying just the `READONLY` flag and passing the normal database name as the first argument. (I think you need to precede the db name with `file:` anyway in URI mode). Alternatively, use only the `URI` flag, and then use `file:database.db?mode=ro&immutable=1`.

Comment: @BoBTFish looks like `SQLITE_OPEN_URI` enables URI filenames but non-uris still work: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html "If URI filename interpretation is enabled, and the filename argument begins with "file:", then the filename is interpreted as a URI"

Comment: @AlanBirtles `database.db?immutable=1` is not a non-URI, so it would need the `file:` prefix.

Comment: @BoBTFish yep, didn't spot that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `SQLITE_OPEN_URI` "the filename can be interpreted as a URI". However, for it to be treated as a URI, it must be prefixed with `file:`, else it will be treated as a normal filename.

So you are trying to open a file named `database.db?immutable=1`, which obviously doesn't exist. Note that with `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY` "if the database does not already exist, an error is returned". Therefore the simplest fix is simply to make the string be `file:database.db?immutable=1`.

However I suggest you stick to only one method of providing special options; use the `SQLITE_OPEN_URI` flag, and put all the other options into the URI, like so: `file:database.db?mode=ro&immutable=1`.

(I realise that not all combinations of options are possible using only a single method, but in your case it is, so I say stick to one and then you don't need to worry about the way different methods interact).

SQLite has extensive documentation, and you can read all about opening databases [here](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html).